# How to build crashpad for Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, chromium, gn

I am developing Qt application and I would like to use crashpad to report crashes. I have downloaded sources and built them.

Now I would like to link those statically to my application.

When I go to out folder I see a lot of .a files. Which one should I choose?

```
> find ./out -name *.a 
./obj/handler/libhandler.a
./obj/snapshot/libsnapshot.a
./obj/snapshot/libtest_support.a
./obj/test/libtest.a
./obj/test/libgtest_main.a
./obj/test/libgmock_main.a
./obj/util/libutil.a
./obj/third_party/mini_chromium/mini_chromium/base/libbase.a
./obj/third_party/gtest/libgtest_main.a
./obj/third_party/gtest/libgtest.a
./obj/third_party/gtest/libgmock.a
./obj/third_party/gtest/libgmock_main.a
./obj/minidump/libminidump.a
./obj/minidump/libtest_support.a
./obj/client/libclient.a
```

Also I have built it using this command:

```
build/gyp_crashpad.py -Dmac_deployment_target=10.12
```

I do not know if I should add some parameters

Could someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly of interest to you, this [CMake / Nuget wrapper for Crashpad](https://github.com/unidentifieddeveloper/crashpad), likely easier and more straightforward to use in a build than the plain libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build Crashpad via `gn` and `ninja`, where `gn` generates a build configuration, and `ninja` does the actual building.

For a macOS Qt application to generate minidumps and upload them to a remote server it will need to be linked with the Crashpad libraries `libcommon.a`, `libclient.a`, `libutil.a`, `libbase.a`, `mig_output.a`:

```
# Crashpad libraries
LIBS += -L$$PWD/Crashpad/Libraries/MacOS/$$ARCH -lcommon
LIBS += -L$$PWD/Crashpad/Libraries/MacOS/$$ARCH -lclient
LIBS += -L$$PWD/Crashpad/Libraries/MacOS/$$ARCH -lbase
LIBS += -L$$PWD/Crashpad/Libraries/MacOS/$$ARCH -lutil
LIBS += -L$$PWD/Crashpad/Libraries/MacOS/$$ARCH -lmig_output
```

The application will also need to be linked with the system library `bsm`, and frameworks `AppKit` and `Security`:

```
# System libraries
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/ -lbsm
LIBS += -framework AppKit
LIBS += -framework Security
```

Additionally, you'll need to package `crashpad_handler` with your application and ensure that it is available at runtime.

More information about building Crashpad can be found [here](https://www.bugsplat.com/docs/sdk/crashpad/building/).

An example macOS Qt application that has been integrated with Crashpad can be found [here](https://github.com/BugSplat-Git/myQtCrasher).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe type this in your code:

```
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    # Print the error and traceback
    print(exctype, value, traceback)
    # Call the normal Exception hook after
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.exit(1)
# Set the exception hook to our wrapping function
sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook
```

Also, import sys.   This Code prints the error and reports it.